# How to run Karate tests when using the stand alone installer in Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, karate, azure-pipelines-yaml

Could you please share how to get the karate tests running in azure pipelines when using the stand alone installer?

We dont use java in our project and hence it would be handy for us to use the standalone installer.

Is it possible to get the tests running using the stand alone server in devops?

Comment: even if you use the maven option, your team can continue to use vs-code and not have to compile java code

Comment: You can always have a docker image that contains the jar file. and then use docker commands in azure cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only pre-requisite for the stand-alone JAR is a JRE, and my guess is that it may even be pre-installed on Azure boxes, but it should be easy for you to check with your team / support-contact and verify this - or get it installed if needed.

Then it is just a matter of shaping your command-line and generating any extra report files needed (JUnit XML or Cucumber JSON).

Refer to other answers on Karate + Azure: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+azure